# PDO query issue with bindParam from function variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query-builder

I have problem with querying by function and binding with used variables.

```
public function get_where($what, $condition, $thing)
    {
        $this->statement = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE :what :condition :thing";

        $stmt = $this->db->pdo()->prepare($this->statement);

        $stmt->bindParam(':what', $what);
        $stmt->bindParam(':condition', $condition);
        $stmt->bindParam(':thing', $thing);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Usage:

```
$result = $QueryBuilder->table('calendar')
    ->get_where('MONTH(date)', '=', '9');

var_dump($result);
```

Result is `empty array`

As you can see I pass to this function `MONTH(date)` as `what`, `=` as `condition` and `9` as `thing`.

But it doesn't work, `empty array`

But when I manually change

`$this->statement = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE :what :condition :thing";`

to

`$this->statement = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE MONTH(date) = 9";`

it works perfectly.

So why is wrong here? : /

---

In addition I can say that by doing

`$result = $QueryBuilder->table('calendar')
    ->get_where('1', '=', '1');`

I get `all rows` in result

Comment: You can't create `placeholder` for `column and table name` in prepare statement.

Comment: You can only bind `:thing`, you need to add `$what` and `$condition` to the statement itself.